# AnalysisException callUDF() inside withColumn()

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This morning we updated Spark version from 2.2.0 to 2.3.0 and I faced with quite strange problem.

I have a UDF(), calculating distnce between 2 points

```
private static UDF4<Double, Double, Double, Double, Double> calcDistance =
        (UDF4<Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>) (lat, lon, meanLat, meanLon) ->
                GeoUtils.calculateDistance(lat, lon, meanLat, meanLon);
```

Registration of UDF

```
spark.udf().register("calcDistance", calcDistance, DataTypes.DoubleType);
```

And I have a dataframe of the following structure (this DF is the result of join of 2 DFs by `hpan` field)

```
root
|-- hpan: string (nullable = true)
|-- atmid: string (nullable = true)
|-- reqamt: long (nullable = true)
|-- mcc_code: string (nullable = true)
|-- utime: string (nullable = true)
|-- udate: string (nullable = true)
|-- address_city: string (nullable = true)
|-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- gmt_msk_offset: integer (nullable = true)
|-- utimeWithTZ: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- weekDay: integer (nullable = true)
|-- location_type: string (nullable = true)
|-- mean_lat: double (nullable = true)
|-- mean_lon: double (nullable = true)
```

So what I want  is to add a column with distance between (lat,lon) and (mean_lat,mean_lon);

```
svWithCoordsTzAndDistancesDF.withColumn("distance",
    callUDF("calcDistance",col("latitude"), col("longitude"), 
            col("mean_lat"), col("mean_lon")));
```

It works well on Spark 2.2, but starts to fail on v2.3
The exception is

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Resolved attribute(s) 'mean_lon,'mean_lat,'longitude,'latitude missing
>   from gmt_msk_offset#147,utime#3,longitude#146,addre
>   ss_city#141,udate#29,mean_lon#371,weekDay#230,reqamt#4L,latitude#145,mean_lat#369,location_type#243,hpan#1,utimeWithTZ#218,mcc_code#14,atmid#9
>   in operator 'Project [hpan#1, atmid#9, reqamt#              4L,
>   mcc_code#14, utime#3, udate#29, address_city#141, latitude#145,
>   longitude#146, gmt_msk_offset#147, utimeWithTZ#218, weekDay#230,
>   location_type#243, mean_lat#369, mean_lon#371, 'calcDist
>   ance('latitude, 'longitude, 'mean_lat, 'mean_lon) AS distance#509].
>   Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation:
>   mean_lon,mean_lat,longitude,latitude. Please check if the right
>   attribute(s) are used.;;

I tried to add aliases to cols inside UDF() like this

```
svWithCoordsTzAndDistancesDF.withColumn("distance",
        callUDF("calcDistance",col("latitude").as("a"), col("longitude").as("b"), col("mean_lat").as("c"), col("mean_lon").as("d")));
```

Or wrap this cols in scala sequence

```
svWithCoordsTzAndDistancesDF.withColumn("distance",
        callUDF("calcDistance",JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(Arrays.asList
                (col("latitude"), col("longitude"), col("mean_lat"), col("mean_lon")))
                .asScala()
                .toSeq()));
```

None of this attemps solve the issue.

Maybe someone knows the workaround for this problem?

The transformations flow is like this

```
ParentDF -> childDF1(as parentDF.groupBy().agg(mean())), childDF2(parentDF.filter('condition')) -> svWithCoordsTzAndDistancesDF (join childDF1 and childDF2).
```

I think problem may be in execution plan builded for this flow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's some kind of magic. When I specify the column's dataframe and add `select("*")` - it works. If someone can explain it - I'll be very thankful

```
df = df.select("*")
       .withColumn("distance", callUDF("calcDistance",
                df.col("latitude"),
                df.col("longitude"),
                df.col("mean_lat"),
                df.col("mean_lon")))
      .toDF();
```